# Lead to Contact conversion with custom relationships

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

So I have a custom object that have lookup fields for Leads and Contacts. When a user converts a Lead to a Contact, how would I make it so that custom object's Lead value propagates to the Contact field as well?

Comment: so starting condition is lead L is parent of custom object X; then lead is converted to a contact C and you want custom object X to now have Contact C as its new parent?

Comment: Yes. Custom object X has lookup fields for both Lead and Contact. When Lead conversion happens, I want that lookup field for Lead to also propagate to Contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to solve this with an after update trigger on Lead.  Something like this:

```
trigger LeadConversionCleanup on Lead (after update) {
 List<CustomObj__c> customObjUpdList = new List<CustomObj__c> ();
 // Get only converted leads in the trigger list plus all children
 for (Lead l : [select id, ConvertedContactId,
                    (select id from customObj__r)
                  from Lead where isConverted = true and
                              id IN : Trigger.new]) 
    for (CustomObj__c c : l.customObj__r) // could be 0+ children
      // re-point CustomObj to converted contact 
      customObjUpdList.add(new CustomObj__c (id = c.id,
                                             contact__c = l.ConvertedContactId,
                                             lead__c = null));

 update customObjUpdList;    
}
```

Code presumes that `CustomObject__c` has two lookup fields: `Lead__c` and `Contact__c`

*Above was typed in and may have typos*